# Execute the script owned by root from C++ code

Tags: c++, root, setuid

I am trying to run a script from my c++ code owned by root.
But it throws me an error **permission denied** to run the script.

Permissions on files are as follows:

```
-rwx------ 1 root    mygame   39 Dec 24 19:11 script.sh
-rwsr-xr-x 1 gag5kor mygame 7999 Dec 26 12:23 a.out
```

C++ code:

```
   int err = system("./script.sh");
   cout << "Before err: " << err << endl;

   cout << "setuid: " << seteuid(0) << endl;

   err = system("./script.sh");
   cout << "After err: " << err << endl;
```

getuid() and geteuid() function returns me same value (say 1234) even after I call setuid(0) to get the root permissions.

What I am doing wrong here?

I read the other answers on stackoverflow but not able to understand properly.

Comment: Why do you think a simple function call (seteuid) is enough to get root access from a non-root program? Of course it's not that easy.

Comment: @deviantfan how can I achieve what I am trying. Can you please tell what all modifications will be required.

Comment: people who have downvoted can you please explain the reason for the same.

Comment: First decide what you want. a) Running the script owned by root [with the permissions of your user account], as you're saying, or b) running the script owned by root *as root*, which is what you're trying in the code apparently. .Then tell us too as which user your a.out program should run. Then tell us what "other answers" you read and what part you couldn't understand. Then tell us why you're mixing EUID and UID. Then tell us why you thought your seteuid call will work. ... etc.etc.

Comment: One of the downvotes is from me because there are so many unclear and nonsensical things here, but I'll gladly reverse it if you can answer these things.

Comment: @deviantfan 
1. script is owned by root.

Comment: @deviantfan 
1. script is owned by root and only root has execute permissions.
2. normal user other than root will execute the a.out file. As script is not accessible to normal user other than root, so I am trying to gain root privileges to run the script.
3. Whatever I am trying is it possible.
4. Can i achieve sudo kind of behavior through code?

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the question 2) Neither does this 3) Upgrading the permissions of some existing program while running is not possible. The only time where a process can get root permissions is when it is started. And no, doing something like sudo in your code is not possible either; sudo just works because of it's SUID [which needs root permissions to set if you want it for your own program, so no help either]

Answer (score -1):

`chmod 0555 script.sh` should fix this

**EDIT**

```
chown root script.sh
chmod 0500 script.sh
```

Should fulfill your requirements

Comment: If I do chmod 0555 then this script can be run by everyone. I want only root should be able to execute script file. So I have given permission as 0700 to script.sh